# SQL Select Distinct Values, but order by a different value and also select corresponding values from other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
stackId  userId  value
s1       u1      21
s1       u2      13
s1       u1      14
s2       u3      91
s2       u2      44
```

where i want to find out all distinct stackIds, and the largest value for each unique stackId, and the corresponding userId, namely:

```
s1       u1      21
s2       u3      91
```

I know how to select distinct and then order by max value:

```
select distinct(stackId), max(value) from table group by stackId order by stackId;
```

which would give me

```
s1       21
s2       91
```

but I am having hard time getting the userId that corresponds to the max value for that stackId, can someone kindly shed some light?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH CTE(stackId,  userId,  value) AS 
  (

    SELECT 's1',       'u1' ,     21 UNION ALL 
    SELECT's1' ,      'u2',      13  UNION ALL 
    SELECT's1'  ,     'u1',      14  UNION ALL 
    SELECT's2'   ,    'u3' ,     91  UNION ALL 
    SELECT's2'    ,   'u2',      44   
 )
SELECT X.stackId,X.userId,X.VALUE FROM
(
   SELECT C.stackId,C.userId,C.value,
      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY C.stackId ORDER BY C.value DESC)AS XCOL
     FROM CTE AS C
)AS X WHERE X.XCOL=1
```

You can use WINDOW-function ROW_NUMBER() to achieve this. CTE in the upper query represents data you have provided